# How to remove SophosEndpoint "phantom" user?

Tags: user-account, migration

I recently migrated from a 2017 Macbook Pro to a 2019 Macbook Pro (both running Catalina) using Migration Assistant, and ever since then I've had this "phantom" SophosEndpoint user stuck on the log in screen:

[image]
I have since uninstalled Sophos (manually, their automated uninstaller didn't work), but this user is still there.

I've checked the Users folder, and nothing related to Sophos exists:

```
pmaiorana@pm-mbp-2019 ~ % ls -l /Users
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  14 root       wheel   448 Oct 22 16:19 Shared
drwxr-xr-x@ 55 pmaiorana  staff  1760 Oct 22 16:23 pmaiorana
```

And there's nothing in the users panel in System Preferences:

[image]

What can I do to remove it?